# Definir key para un objeto en una función

Tags: javascript

La función debe regresar un objeto como el siguiente:

> {Kevin : 'Spacey'}

Pero estoy regresando esto:  `{ first: 'Spacey' }`

La función es la siguiente:

```
 function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var obj = {};
  var first = array.shift();
  var last = array.pop();
  obj.first = last;

  console.log(obj);
  //return obj;
}

transformFirstAndLast(['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo sería necesario considerar `obj[first] = last;`.

```js
 function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var obj = {};
  var first = array.shift();
  var last = array.pop();
  
  obj[first] = last;
  
  console.log(obj);
}

transformFirstAndLast(['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey']);
```